# Reference Request: Finding an Op-Ed by J. Hammersley

Tags: reference-request

I'm interested in finding an online copy of J. Hammersley's article entitled *On the enfeeblement of mathematical skills by Modern Mathematics and by similiar soft intellectual trash in schools and universities*, which was published in the Bulletin of the Institute of Mathematics and its Applications, Band 4, 1968, S. 66–85.

I've searched both the name of the article, truncated version with hammersley, and even tried to find a repository for the "Bulletin of the Institute of Mathematics and its Applications", yet unfortunately, all have failed.

Anyone know where to find this?

Comment: See [this](http://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/BF00426226) for a summary.

Comment: @RobertIsrael. Thank you, Prof. Israel! I did indeed see that summary. Any thoughts on whether I might be able to find the fulltext online?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[This](http://www.inp.nsk.su/~silagadz/Hammersley_Modern_Mathematics.pdf) should be the mentioned article.

Comment: Indeed it is! Thank you!