# What are some books on history and development of calculus?

Tags: soft-question, book-recommendation

I am well versed with modern calculus but I want to know how people in history developed the subject. I want to learn how Newton and Leibniz came up with it, what Greeks did with the method of exhaustion et cetera

Comment: I liked [Calculus Gems](https://www.amazon.com/Calculus-Gems-Memorable-Moments-Spectrum/dp/147045128X/) by George Simmons.

Comment: The Historical Development of the Calculus by C.H. Edwards.

Comment: See https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2209002/589

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Calculus Gallery: Masterpieces from Newton to Lebesgue by William Dunham.

It's easy to follow, provides the most important examples or methods by Newton, Weirstrass, Cauchy, Cantor and so on. It also explains some basic concepts, but I like it mostly for its easiness to understand and follow.

Link here: [https://www.amazon.com/Calculus-Gallery-Masterpieces-Newton-Lebesgue/dp/0691136262/ref=sr_1_1?ie=UTF8&s=books&qid=1273235330&sr=8-1](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0691136262)